# ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional error for Swift 4.0 code, Xcode 10.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode10

I have a framework that is written on Swift 4, that have extension of `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type and XCode 10.0 throw an error when compiling.

I know that `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` is deprecated in Swift 4.2, but I have selected '*Swift 4*' in *'Swift Language Version*' in target build settings.

Does it have to be this way? Is any workaround to use Xcode 10 without converting all the Swift 4 code to 4.2? I selected '*use legacy build settings*' in workspace settings, but it didn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately Swift 4.0 mode of Swift 4.2 compiler does not work exactly the same as Swift 4.0 compiler. There's no `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` as a distinct type from `Optional` in Swift 4.2 compiler and the supporting runtime for it. You may need to continue using Xcode 9.x, or completely reconsider the design around the extension.

Comment: @OOPer, thanks for the explanation. It seems that using XCode 9 is the only solution.